# Create Outlook Add-in that opens a browser with url

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

does anyone knows how to create Outlook Addin that opens a browser with url without using taskPane?
to just click on the button and the action to preform.
also. I haven't seen any option to use the add-in unless its itemRead / EditItem, does anyone knows how to do it?
thank :)

I've tried to add the window.open("URL"), but it didn't work, the outlook just saying that working on your perform an action request.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in the [openBrowserWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-openbrowserwindow-member(1)) method which opens a browser window and loads the specified URL. The `OpenBrowserWindow API` set enables add-ins to open a browser to accomplish tasks that cannot always be done in the sandboxed webview control within the add-in itself; for example, downloading a PDF file when the webview control is provided by Microsoft Edge.

The `OpenBrowserWindowApi 1.1` requirement set is only available as follows:

- Excel, PowerPoint, Word: Windows, Mac, iPad
- Outlook: Windows, Mac

Read more about the supported host versions in the [Open Browser Window API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/open-browser-window-api-requirement-sets?view=powerpoint-js-preview) article.